# error opening firefox with selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have this error when open firefox

"Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055"

[image]

is not correct this line?

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

it's because I only use Visual Studio without Nunit? Firefox can be open usiong C# no? because I'm using C# not java.

Comment: Which version of Firefox and Webdriver are you using?

Comment: selenium-dotnet- version 2.42.0 - and the last version of firefox

Comment: Try to update your Selenium version. My Webdriver has already 2.46.0.